# PyQt lineEdit is empty when called from another script

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is my mainscript which calls some generated UI and defines a few functions:

```
import uifile

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, uifile.Ui_MyWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_clickMe.clicked.connect(self.some_function)
        return
    def some_function(self):
        import otherpyscript
    def input_user(self):
        user = self.lineEdit_username.text()
        return user

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = App()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the other script where I call the function from mainscript:

```
...
import mainscript

print("The user input from your other script is: " + mainscript.App().input_user())
```

I'm trying to get `mainscript.App().input_user()` to not show up as empty (the default for PyQt).

Comment: Well, `object1` is new instance of `App()`, so obviously its line-edit will be empty.

Comment: @ekhumoro oh... how shall I call it then?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33534274/edit) and add the code there. You should also explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @ekhumoro I tried creating another class which inherits from the LoginApp class and run the function through that, but no luck. Perhaps, running the function internally as self and then setting that as some global variable?

Comment: Still waiting for you to action my previous request ;-)

Comment: @ekhumoro Terribly sorry, I somehow missed that first part. Have now edited the question to be more clear with all required code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

On second thoughts, the right approach depends on how `mainscript` is used. If it is used as the start-up script, it will not be initially imported, which then complicates things when it comes to accessing its globals later on.

A better approach is to have a very simple start-up script that only has this in it:

```
# mainscript
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from mainmodule import main
    main()
```

The `mainmodule` would then look like this:

```
# mainmodule
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import uifile

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, uifile.Ui_MyWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_clickMe.clicked.connect(self.some_function)
    def some_function(self):
        import othermodule
        othermodule.print_user()
    def input_user(self):
        user = self.lineEdit_username.text()
        return user

form = None

def main_window():
    return form

def main():
    global form
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = App()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

And `othermodule` would look like this:

```
# othermodule
import mainmodule

def print_user():
    print("user input: " + mainmodule.main_window().input_user())
```

Comment: It is currently still printing an empty string. What I have done: Replaced my class code with yours, tried with no-argument version also, tried defining a print function in my other script and then calling that print function in `some_function()`.

Comment: Perfect! I have next to no idea what's happening but that's something I can work on. Thanks for sticking through the problem with me.

Comment: @Prof. It is quite tricky. The script which starts an application doesn't get added to `sys.modules`. So if you explicitly import it again later on, all its code will be *re-executed*. This is different to all other modules, which will only ever be executed *once*. If they are imported again later on, python will re-use the module object that's stored in `sys.modules`. This has implications for any global variables that are set when a module is first executed. For start-up scripts that are re-imported, the global variables will not be the same.

Comment: Could I trouble you with another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701243/pyqt-thread-still-running-after-window-closed), I feel like it's linked to this one in that it is a problem with initialising/executing.