# PyQt thread still running after window closed

Tags: python, qt, exec, pyqt5, qapplication

When I close an application window in PyQt the console is still left running in the background and python.exe process is present until I close the console. I think the `sys.exit(app.exec_())` is not able to operate properly.

**Mainscript** (which opens Firstwindow):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from firstwindow import main
    main()
```

**Firstwindow**

On button press:

```
    self.close() #close firstprogram
    Start() #function to open mainprogram
```

Start():

```
def Start():
        global MainWindow
        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = genui_MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
```

main() (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534274/pyqt-lineedit-is-empty-when-called-from-another-script/33557109#33557109)):

```
def main_window():
     return form

def main():
    global form
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    form = MyApp()  
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why are you starting the application twice in succession? The second time you call `exec_()` it will just sit there doing nothing, and you won't be able to interact with it because you have already closed the main window. Get rid of the first `app.exec_()` line.

Comment: @ekhumoro That did the trick, you can post it as an answer. However, I'd like to know where I call exec the second time as I'm not understanding it. Isn't exec telling qt's engine to handle the running of the program and then me putting exec in sys.exit tells the script to exit when Qt says so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `exec_()` twice in the `main()` function:

```
def main():
    global form
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    form = MyApp()  
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The first `app.exec_()` line will start an event-loop, which means the `main()` function will pause there while you interact with the gui. When you close the top-level window (or call `quit()` on the application), the event-loop will stop, `exec_()` will return, and the `main()` function will continue.

But the next line calls `sys.exit(app.exec_())`, which *restarts* the event-loop, and pauses the `main()` function again - including the `sys.exit()` call, which must wait for `exec_()` to return. However, it will wait forever, because there is now no gui to interact with, and so there's nothing you can to do to stop the event-loop other than forcibly terminating the script.